# Is it possible to change or reconfigure a domain owner on SDE?

Tags: enterprise-geodatabase, server, domains

We have had to reconfigure a few things within a geodatabase managed in SDE. This inadvertently has caused some issues updating the domains within the gdb, to the point where not even the DBO can update a domain, only the originator. The DBO and owner are actually the same user/person now. Does anyone know of a method to change the domain owner to the DBO, rather than the listed user that originated the domain? We are trying to get around the message...

"Failed to update one of the domains. Must be the owner to perform this operation."

Comment: When it comes to unsupported procedures to overcome geodatabase metadata corruption, it's best to talk with Tech Support directly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't work to just give a user "db_owner" permissions. The SDE admin will have to use the script below in MSSQL:

> update sde.gdb_domains
>
> set Owner = 'USER'
>
> where DomainName = 'DOMAIN1' or DomainName = 'DOMAIN2' or DomainName = 'DOMIAN3'